# Commit to Submodule from post-commit hook

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I am currently trying to update a submodule after committing in my main repository. But git is failing with errors like

```
fatal: Unable to create '/Users/jhbruhn/georenting-server/GeoRentingServer/georenting-server-endpoint/.git/index.lock': Not a directory
```

or

```
fatal: index file open failed: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The Problem was that some Environment-variables were set due to the fact that it was executed by a hook. I reset those in the scripts and now it works:

```
GIT_DIR=""
GIT_INDEX_FILE=""
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `unset`

```
unset GIT_DIR
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
```